# Como evitar chamadas a função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho em meus sistemas uma chamada para uma função de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e sempre funcionou. É uma função para exibir/esconder uma imagem de carregando para o usuário. O problema é que as vezes eu tenho que chamar essa função em uma ação do usuário de um campo `select`, por exemplo, e caso o usuário fique altere 10 vezes seguidas esse campo select irá fazer 10 chamadas, o que não tem problemas, mas é ruim para o usuário ficar aparecendo ainda a imagem pois ele fica carregando e sumindo as 10 vezes.

Segue um exemplo para melhor entendimento do que estou dizendo.

Nesse caso não é nenhuma ação que demore para executar, mas por eu ter muitas chamadas de ajax que podem demorar um pouco mais, daí a necessidade de eu exibir para o usuário que esta carregando.

Meu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $("select[name=meuSelect]").change(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         var valor = $(this).val();

         ajaxLoadAni('In');     
         $("#valor").text(valor);     
         ajaxLoadAni('Out');
     });
});


function ajaxLoadAni(inOut) {
    'use strict';

    if (inOut === 'In') {
      $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeIn('slow'); //EXIBE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO
    } else {
        $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeOut('slow'); //ESCONDE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO
    }
}
```

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9q8/1/)

Comment: Será que poderia mostrar o código relevante?

Comment: Esta ali o link http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9q8/1/ de todo código @Tivie

Comment: Obrigado, não tinha visto

Comment: Sem crise... caso vá alterando o select com as setas do teclado fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Um `stop` da animação antes do fadeIn resolveria? http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9q8/2/

Comment: @bfavaretto resolve sim, falta um pouco de conhecimento mesmo. Valew. Deixe como resposta para pode ficar melhor sinalizado né.

Comment: @bfavaretto não seria um stop no fadeOut?

Comment: Sei que não é o foco, mas vale lembrar uma melhor forma de usar o `document.ready`, usando [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression (em inglês)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). [Exemplo aqui](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9618702). Abraço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode resolver isto facilmente parando a animação utilizando `.stop()` antes de dar `.fadeOut()` e pode ficar melhor ainda se você também dar um `.stop()` no `.fadeIn()` também pois eu realizei alguns testes e se você trocar muito rapidamente você percebe que a animação se repetiu uma vez, por isso:

Você estava utilizando `fadeIn()` e `fadeOut()` sem parada:

```
$('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeIn('slow'); //EXIBE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO
$('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeOut('slow'); //ESCONDE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO
```

Adicionando uma parada ficaria assim:

```
$('#ajaxLoadAni').stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow'); //EXIBE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO    
$('#ajaxLoadAni').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow'); //ESCONDE A IMAGEM DE CARRREGANDO
```

Desta forma você irá parar a animação anterior antes de sair, assim não tendo que mostrar/esconder várias vezes para o usuário.

## Detalhe importante sobre a função stop():

Os parâmetros da função `.stop()` servem para limpar a fila de animações e também finaliza-las, que seriam:

> ### stop([clearQueue],[jumpToEnd])
>
> **[clearQueue]** - Caso *true*, indica que a animação deve ser removida da fila.(default *false*).
>   **[jumpToEnd]** - Caso *true*, indica que a animação deve ser completada imediatamente.(default *false*).

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ9q8/3/)

## [Referência](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: O que faz o `false, true` que você passou como parâmetro? Eu havia pensado em um stop no fadeIn pois ele só teria efeito caso já houvesse um fadeOut em andamento.

Comment: @Paulo, me diga uma coisa, nesse caso qual a diferença em si. E pelo que pude perceber no fadeOut não funcionou

Comment: E o que melhor funcionou  foi $('#ajaxLoadAni').stop( true, true ).fadeIn('slow');

Comment: editei a resposta te explicando @bfavaretto

Comment: beleza @MarceloDiniz valeu pela dica, notei isso também, mudei ali a resposta ;)

Comment: Outra coisa @MarceloDiniz percebi que utilizando os dois no fadeIn e no fadeOut também fica melhor.

Comment: Valeu, agora entendi.

Answer (score 3):

## Questão do OP:

Pelo que percebi, os passos da sua aplicação (num contexto real) são os seguintes:

- Utilizador selecciona uma opção no menu
- A imagem de loading é activada
- É feito um pedido de AJAX
- No success callback do AJAX a imagem de loading é desactivada

O seu problema é que, por vezes, o utilizador muda a selecção mais rápidamente do que a animação.

Em termos de experiência do utilizador, tem algumas soluções relativamente simples...

1. Accelerar a animação. Em vez de "slow" usar "fast" ou especificar os milisegundos directamente (slow é 600ms, fast é 200ms)
2. Usar `show()` e `hide()` em vez de `fadeIn` e `fadeOut`. Deixa de ter animação e passa a ser instantâneo.

Outra maneira, um pouco mais complexa seria escutar [**o evento ajaxStop**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).
Este evento é disparado quando não existem mais pedidos de AJAX na pilha.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    ajaxLoadAni('Out');
});
```

Assim, só quando todos os pedidos de ajax terminarem é que a animação é escondida. Se aliar isto a uma das soluções que apresentei ou à sugestão sugerida pelo Paulo Roberto, a experiência do utilizador melhora.

---

## Problema dos multiplos pedidos:

No entanto, assumindo que a esquematização que fiz dos passos da sua aplicação está correcta, existe um problema maior, que é o número de chamadas AJAX que podem ser disparadas quase em simultâneo.

Por exemplo, se o utilizador utilizar as setas para mudar o select e carregar alternadamente na tecla de cima e na tecla de baixo 25 vezes, terá 25 pedidos de AJAX quase simultâneos, num curtíssimo espaço de tempo. Se o fizer 2500 vezes... imagine.

---

## Solução para o problema dos multiplos pedidos:

A solução mais simples (e mais limpa) seria adicionar um botão que chamasse a função que faz o pedido AJAX, em vez de escutar o "*change*" event do "*select*"

```
$('.ajaxBtn').click(function () {
    //Chamar ajax aqui
});
```

Também pode desactivar o select enquanto o pedido de ajax não terminou, mas isso pode piorar a experiência do utilizador.

Outra forma, para manter a interface como está, seria colocar uma "flag" que impedisse multiplos AJAX requests de dispararem ao mesmo tempo e só quando o anterior estivesse resolvido é que aceitaria um novo.

```
 var ajaxFlag = false;
 $("select[name=meuSelect]").change(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     var valor = $(this).val();
     if (ajaxFlag === false) {
         ajaxLoadAni('In');
         ajaxFlag = true;
         //Funcao AJAX
         $.ajax()
            .success(function() //Quando é bem sucessida
            {
                $("#valor").text(valor);
            })
            //.error() //QUando dá erro
            .complete(function() //é sempre chamada
            {
                ajaxLoadAni('Out');
                ajaxFlag = false;
            })
        }       
 });
```

O problema desta solução é que desincroniza o menu select, isto é, se eu mudar rapidamente de opção, ele vai ignorar a segunda opção e mostrar só a primeira, ainda que no menu select esteja selecciona a segunda.

Tem também a opção de dar um delay entre a selecção e o pedido de ajax.

Comment: é quase que isso mesmo que você descreveu. Agora vamos lá: Eu até poderia sim ter colocado "fast" (tanto que na função real minha isso esta como parametro, só deixei o mais limpo possível) mas não deixei pois o interessante já que é uma chamada ajax foi preferível deixar no slow mesmo, e também poderia usar o show e hide, mas da mesma forma foi escolhido ter a animação. E sim, isso pode acontecer de ter as 2500 chamadas, infelizmente, se tiver algo para isso tbm ajuda. E valew mesmo pelos comentários