# Qual e a diferença de ON para ONE no Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou lidando com algumas otimizações corriqueiras no meu sistema e encontrei uma situação que me intrigou,toda vez que eu fazia um clique duplo na tabela e chamava uma função para trazer os dados complementares do cliente o mesmo  duplicava a quantidade de solicitações ao php, isto acontece porque eu estava a usar o evento `on`, então eu realizei algumas pesquisar e descobri o método `one`, que executa o método apenas uma vez. esta função parece ser nova, nas versões 1.7 do `Jquery` utilizava apenas o `live` e funcionava corretamente.
Então minha dúvida e a seguinte, devo usar `one` se minha intenção e chamar uma função apenas uma vez  ou devo usar `on` e `off` ?

```
   $('#clientes tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
      $('#cobradores tbody tr').removeClass('btn-success');
      $(this).addClass('btn-success');
      codigo = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
      acao = 'update';
      $("#clientes").modal('show');
   });

   $('#clientesModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      if (acao === 'update') {
         dados = {PREUPDATE: true, CODIGO: codigo};
         buscaCobradores(dados);
      }
   });
```

Comment: A letra E :) Não conheço jQuery mas acredito que o novo método foi criado justamente para evitar a situação que descreveu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para quando você só quer que execute uma vez por tipo, exemplo:

```
$(".target").one("click mouseenter", function() {
  $(".count").html(++n);
});
```

Vai executar o código uma vez quando clicar e uma vez quando passar o mouse.

É mais adequado usar `.one()`, porem com `.on()` e `.off()` da para ter o mesmo resultado, exemplo com `.one()`:

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Agora mesmo código usando `.on()` e `.off()`:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  $( this ).off( event );
});
```

Fonte = http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 5):

Seguindo a descrição e o problema que tens eu diria que precisas de fazer debounce e não de `.on()`. Debounce é uma função que evita que uma outra função seja corrida, por engano, vezes demais ou próximas uma da outra. [Dei uma resposta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54052/129) que pode ser util aqui.

Para esclarecer conceitos:

### `.on()`

O `.on()` é o método para adicionar oscultador de eventos. Recebe o tipo de evento e uma [função callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129). Ela será corrido quantas vezes o evento fôr detetado/emitido.

O `.live()` é basicamente o mesmo que o `.on()`.

### `.off()`

O `.off()` é o inverso do `.on()`, ou seja remove o oscultador de eventos. Nota que o argumento callback deve ser a mesma instância da função usada no `.on()`. Quando usado sem parâmetros remove todos os oscultadores em modo "força bruta".

### `.one()`

O `.one()` é o mesmo que o `on()` mas só corre uma vez, e nunca mais!

### debounce / flag

Se quiseres podes usar debounce para evitar que uma callback seja chamada vezes demais. Nesse caso podes usar:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

e defenir qual o intervalo minimo em que a mesma função pode ser chamada.

Utilização:

```
var dbFn = debounce(minhaFuncaoOriginal, 200);
$('#id').on('click', dbFn);
```

Pode ser contudo que o melhor seja usar uma flag. Nesse caso tens uma variável que impede um pedido ajax de ser corrido enquanto o outro não tiver sido recebido, e assim evitar conteúdo duplo. Nesse caso dá uma olhada a [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9157/129). (Vou juntar aqui um exemplo mais logo)

Comment: fiz o teste usando o `debounce,flag`  e funcionaram perfeitamente fiz também assim : `  $('#clientes tbody').off(); ` e funcionou, pelos meus testes usar one não irá funcionar a adição e remoção de classes para dar aquele efeito de `hover` por acionar a ação apenas uma vez.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues ótimo que funcionou. Tu saberás qual a maneira que mais te convém. Se houver alguma coisa que não esteja clara diz.